# trying to fetch all the images in a page using xpath

Tags: php, xpath

i am trying to catch all the images on a page using Xpath and then iterating through the node list checking if the image has attribute if it does i iterate through the attributes till i get to src now my problem is when i get relative paths like `/us/english/images/12/something.jpeg` or something like that.. my question is: is there a way go get the full path ?

I thought of regex the returned src and look for host if host isn't there use the site's url but that can be hard to check for..

i also thought maybe i should parse url and check for ['host'] part if the host part has "."dot meaning there is host and i shouldn't add it ?

Here is what i have so far:

```
$image_list = $xpath->query('//img');
    foreach($image_list as $element){
        if($element->hasAttributes()){
            foreach($element->attributes as $attribute){
                if(strtolower($attribute->nodeName) == 'src'){
                    echo $attribute->nodeName. ' = ' .$attribute->nodeValue.'<br>';
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

would appreciate any help.

Comment: From where youre fetching that data? Mysql? Anyway if there is no url, its obviously that images are stored on your domain.. If not so, you will then see a full url.

Comment: fetching them from other hosts. and not i you dont always see full url

Comment: You can gett all `src` attributes just evaluating this XPath expression: `//img/@src`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Change your xpath query to `//img[src]`. This will return all the `img` elements that has `src` attribute. Use `getAttribute` method.your code will be shorter and efficient.

   ```
   $image_list = $xpath->query("//img[@src]");
   for($i=0;$i<$image_list->length; $i++){
       echo "src = ". $image_list->item($i)->getAttribute("src"). "\n";
   }
   ```
2. About the relative paths problem, you should find the [`base` elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/base.html) `href` attribute. If its found use it as base URI for relative urls. If its not found try to find the URL of this document. That'll be the base URI.

#### Update

As you want to read the image file path in the complex url like

```
//lp.hm.com/hmprod?set=key[source],value[/environment/2012/P01_2972_044R_0.‌​‌​jpg]&amp;set=key[rotate],value[0.65]&amp;set=key[width],value[2921]&amp;set=key[‌​h‌​eight],value[3415]&amp;set=key[x],value[1508]&amp;set=key[y],value[495]&amp;se‌​t=k‌​ey[type],value[FASHION_FRONT]&amp;call=url[file:/product/large]
```

you better use a custom parser like this,

```
$url = $image_list->item($i)->getAttribute("src");
$q = strpos($url, "?");
$query = substr($url, $q+1);
$params = explode("&", html_entity_decode($query));
$data = array();
foreach($params as $e){
    if(preg_match("/key\[([^\]]+)\],value\[([^\]]+)\]/", $e, $m))
        $data[$m[1]]=$m[2];
    elseif(preg_match("/call=([^\[]+)\[([^\]]+)\]/", $e, $m))
        $data[$m[1]]=$m[2];
}

print_r($data);
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/XUiTlW)

Comment: Thanks for that answer very usefull.i have now problem with images that their urls is weird

Comment: This is the rule of parsing urls in html document. You have to follow this rule and build the full url if its relative one

Comment: yea your solution is efficient and will work in most case but in cases where the url is not normal it wont - which is what i am stucked on now  Something like : `set=source[/environment/2012/P01_2972_044R_0.jpg],rotate[0.65],width[2921],height[3415],x[1508],y[495],type[FASHION_FRONT]&call=url[file:/product/thumb]` will just not work

Comment: The relative paths problem I've solved but look at the above URL you'll understand what i am talking about I'll have to find how the this path works for every site - if that makes sense

Comment: @Nata thats a url with lots of parameters and special characters. But still a url. A browser finds base elements href and prepend it or prepend the Request URL.

Comment: Could you show the full Element for example that is problematic to you?

Comment: the full src ? or how do you mean ?  Check : `http://www.hm.com//lp.hm.com/hmprod?set=source[/environment/2012/P13_0004_111R_0.jpg],rotate[1.2],width[2999],height[3507],x[941],y[275],type[FASHION_FRONT]&call=url[file:/product/thumb]` this is the full URL

Comment: - ah wait i did not solve the problem with the relative urls !

Comment: Full Elements. Not the source. Better you give me the URL of the html document.

Comment: sorry for my ignorance but how do i do that ?

Comment: `<img src=".. some url ..">` is an element and `.. some url ..` is the source. Show me the Element.

Comment: `<img style="position: absolute; left: 0px; right: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;" src="//lp.hm.com/hmprod?set=key[source],value[/environment/2012/P01_2972_044R_0.jpg]&amp;set=key[rotate],value[0.65]&amp;set=key[width],value[2921]&amp;set=key[height],value[3415]&amp;set=key[x],value[1508]&amp;set=key[y],value[495]&amp;set=key[type],value[FASHION_FRONT]&amp;call=url[file:/product/large]" alt="" id="product-image" class="FASHION_FRONT zoom-image" data-type="FASHION_FRONT">` is the complete element

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21974/discussion-between-shiplu-mokadd-im-and-neta-meta)